# domain controller 2012r2 is not listening working on port 445 - how should I fix?

Tags: domain-controller

Checked SMB Service Status:
Ensured that the Server service (LanmanServer) was running on the server where you're experiencing the issue. You can check this by opening the Services management console (services.msc) and verifying that the Server service is set to "Automatic" startup and is currently running.

Windows Firewall Configuration: Turned off in group policy management

Anti-Virus or Security Software: Disabled

Network Configuration:
Confirmed that the server has the correct network configuration, including IP address, subnet mask, and DNS settings. Ensure that DNS is resolving server names correctly.

Checked for Errors in Event Viewer:
Review the Event Viewer logs on the server for any error messages related to SMB or port 445. These logs can provide valuable information about the issue.

Group Policies:
Examined Group Policies for any settings that might be affecting SMB or port 445. Group Policies can be used to configure various aspects of network communication.  No issues, compared to other domain controllers, nothing out of the ordinary.

SMB Configuration: Checked "Group Policy Management Console."  No issues with SMB in group policy.

Network Trace:  Not done - no wireshark at this moment

Restart Services:  Already did this!!
Try restarting the Server service (LanmanServer) and Workstation service (LanmanWorkstation) on the server to see if that resolves the issue.

Update Network Drivers: Not done
Make sure that network adapter drivers on the server are up to date. Outdated or incompatible drivers can lead to network issues.

Security Updates:  No updates done before issue
Ensure that the server is up to date with security patches and updates from the OS vendor. Some updates may address known SMB vulnerabilities.

Consider Professional Help: Consulted other engineers, same issue, head scratcher.

Comment: How did you determine this? What does **netstat -a** show on the server?

Comment: That could mean SYSVOL is not shared. `nltest /dsgetdc:domain.com /server:dcname` should have the SYSVOL flag

Comment: "Have you tried switching it off and on again?" Seriously, net cards can get snaky and a power cycle / reset doesn't fix them because POL means they get 5V standby power. Can you shut down, pull the mains power for 20 sec to ensure 5Vsb drains down, and restart?

Comment: Sysvol flag is not showing.

Comment: hard to shutdown an operational dc, would have to be after hours if this happened.

Comment: any other suggestions.  Checked registry keys, nothing out of the ordinary, we are comparing it to another DC in working condition, not same domain obviously

Comment: resolution, opened ipv4 settings on dc, and file share was checked on NIC.  We never saw that when checking the NIC.

Answer (score 0):

resolution, opened ipv4 settings on dc, and file share was checked on NIC. We never saw that when checking the NIC.

Comment: Do you mean it WASN'T checked? Because it should be. And if it wasn't, someone went in and changed it, and it was a dumb idea to do so. No need to ever do that